# Logged in as root and su won't change to another user

Tags: linux, centos

Logged on to a CentOS server over ssh with the 'root' credentials.

When I run `whoami` it reports root as expected:

```
[root@web1 ~]# whoami
root
```

If I try and change to another user account, 'ftp_usr_andy' it doesn't work and leaves me as 'root':

```
[root@web1 ~]# su - ftp_usr_andy
[root@web1 ~]# whoami
root
```

If I inspect the logs in `/var/log/secure` it appears that the session is opened and then closed immediately:

```
[root@web1 ~]# tail /var/log/secure
Jan 31 11:33:43 web1 su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user ftp_usr_andy by root(uid=0)
Jan 31 11:33:43 web1 su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user ftp_usr_andy
```

Why can I not switch to another user, if I'm logged in as root? All I've read says you just run `su - username` and that should be it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify this user has a valid shell in order to login as this user or change current user to it.

Default user shell can be found in `/etc/passwd` file. Usually, services' users don't have a valid shell like `/bin/false` as they don't require login to the server.

You can change user default shell (`bash` for example) using:

```
# usermod -s /bin/bash user_name
```

You can also use:

```
# chsh user_name
```

This will also show you the current shell of this user.

Comment: Ok. The account `ftp_usr_andy` has been created through Plesk. I haven't seen any option in there to give shell access to that user. I guess that's the problem, but not sure how to resolve this.